# ASP.NET Prevent AJAX request from keeping session alive

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have an ajax request that is firing every n number of seconds... as such the ASP.net session timeout never happens.

Can I manipulate the ajax request somehow so that the asp.net session is not kept alive by virtue of this ajax request firing off in the background?

Basically, let the session die!

Cheers for any input or point in the right direction!

Andrew

Comment: You're design appears to be flawed if you want the session to expire at some point. What are you polling the server for every n seconds?

Comment: I don't want an involuntary action constituting user activity. It's polling the number of unread notices that have been sent to the user.

Comment: When you say "session" do you mean literally "session state", or could it be authentication session? Would it be reasonable to let session state slide, but set the authentication to non-sliding, possibly with some manual renewal mechanism based on your own definition of "user activity"?

Comment: Perhaps when the page loads, have another AJAX request configured to fire when the session timeout expires where this would be managed client-side (time stamp of when page loads + actual session timeout in web.config). a setTimeout call with the number of milliseconds based on the session timeout would fire and on the server side, would expire the session.

Another option could be to save a timestamp to the Session and every time you notification polling occurs, you could do the same thing, but check the session time stamp + the session timeout and compare it to DateTime.Now.

Comment: @Snixtor cheers.... to answer your question I mean an authentication session

Answer (score 1):

Use setTimeout function to do this

```
var timeoutID;

    function delayedAlert() {
      timeoutID =window.setTimeout(slowAlert, 25000);//Session Timeout to expire in milliseconds
    }

    function slowAlert() {
      $.ajax({
      });// call Ajax function to clear all sessions.
    }
```

If you have other ajax requests in the same page and want to keep the session active for those requests. Please clear timeout function before that.

```
function clearAlert() {
  window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
}
```

You can call the `delayedAlert` function in window.load function itself. (or $.ready())